# Question on Hold after giving enough details

Tags: discussion

I posted this question on stackoverflow and even after giving enough information I have my question was put on hold. Also it is unclear why it was on hold!

Link to post: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20535125/architecture-net-windows-application

Can someone help me to re-open this or redirect this to correct place? According to 
[prashant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/498705/prashant)

the question can be on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The close reason says "There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs." - this is not about giving enough details. You have a big problem to solve there. Can you break it up and ask for help with each piece?

Comment: I spent few hours on stackoverflow and other places before posting the question. Also, I think I very well formatted the question with the info I have. One thing surely missing is the code sample, which I don't have.

Comment: I think you're gonna need the code sample.  Without it, the question is too broad; any answers about how events might propagate are merely speculation without seeing some code.

Comment: Remember, Stack Overflow is for specific issues with examples of code. What I wanted to hear from the community here was if directing this question to Programmers is the right thing to do.

Answer (score 5):

Your question(s) give us an overview of the jigsaw puzzle you're going to put together. You already identified some interesting pieces of 1500 in total.

Now you ask if this jigsaw once finished will show [the alps with a blue skye](http://www.shopping.com/Ravensburger-Neuschwanstein-Castle-Jigsaw-Puzzle-1500pc/info) and we can't possible tell. We only have been shown 10% of the pieces and we have to fantasize about the implementation.

If you have a rather complete picture of the architecture of your solution and the technical implementation strategy and you can ask on [programmers.stackexchange.com](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to verify your assumptions. If you want to know how/why/if the two single pieces in your hand fit together ask on [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

To be clear: in it's current state your question can use a description of one/more typical user scenario's so it would be easier to understand why you envision those different components. And try to reduce it to one major question if possible.